# White spaces are required between publicId and systemId, but XML looks OK

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb

I just pulled out a piece of code which I wrote a few months ago. The code fetches an XML document from a web server and parses it using JAXB. The last time I tried it worked flawlessly; now I am getting an exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
```

Looking around, this suggests some issues with the XML header data, namely `<!DOCTYPE ...>`. The answer suggests that the statement is misleading: in the case described, systemId was missing altogether, despite the error just complaining about a missing whitespace in front of it.

However, if I get the XML document with a web browser, it doesn’t even contain the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` header.

Parsing an XML document I retrieved a few months back works without issues.

If I diff the document I retrieved today and the one from a few months back, both are exactly the same up to the start of the root element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Capturing the HTTP traffic finally provided the answer (unencrypted connections come in handy at times): Apparently the service switched from HTTP to HTTPS in the last few months, with URLs remaining unchanged otherwise.

Requests to the old URL are answered with `301 Moved Permanently` and the new URL.

When reading from a URL with `java.net.URL.openStream()`, redirects are not followed automatically. Thus, the data it returns is not valid XML, leading to the error message.

Lesson learned for today: *White spaces are required between publicId and systemId* is really just a cryptic way of saying: *Something’s wrong with the XML data you supplied, but we didn’t bother to dig any deeper.*